# How to create a Community User in a scratch org for tests?

Tags: community, salesforcedx, scratch-org

I'm moving some Communities logic over to SFDX format and aiming to use a scratch org for a Continuous Integration build. The test cases I already have create a new User and verify that the User is correctly hooked up to a Contact/Account. I have this scratch org definition in place:

```
{
    "orgName": "cveep dev",
    "edition": "Developer",
    "features": ["Communities"],
    "settings": {
        "orgPreferenceSettings": {
            "networksEnabled": true,
            "s1DesktopEnabled": true
        }
    }
}
```

But to avoid this error in the tests:

> portal account owner must have a role

I need to give the User that owns the Account a Role, but the simplest approach to that causes this error:

> operation on setup object is not permitted after you have updated a
>   non-setup object (or vice versa)

Is using `sfdx data:record:create` and `sfdx data:record:update` to setup the Role on the default User before the tests are run a good way to go? Is there a better way to solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seemed easiest to add an Apex method to an existing class:

```
public class UserBuilder {

    // Called from build code
    public static void ensureRole() {

        if (UserInfo.getUserRoleId() == null) {
            // Avoid "portal account owner must have a role" error
            UserRole ur = new UserRole(DeveloperName = 'PortalAccountOwnerRole', Name = 'Portal Account Owner Role');
            insert ur;
            update new User(Id = UserInfo.getUserId(), UserRoleId = ur.Id);
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

and call that from the Jenkinsfile:

```
stage('Push To Test Org') {
    sh "sfdx force:source:push --targetusername ${SFDC_USERNAME}"
}

stage('Add User Role') {
    sh "echo 'cveep.UserBuilder.ensureRole();' | sfdx force:apex:execute --targetusername ${SFDC_USERNAME}"
}
```

and this works i.e. the role is set up in a transaction before the tests run.

Comment: How do you invoke this method? possible to add as unit test? adding this to my unit tests cause this error - MIXED_DML_OPERATION, DML operation on setup object is not permitted after you have updated a non-setup object (or vice versa): UserRole, original object: Account: []

Comment: Yes, the method needs to be called from a separate transaction; in our case that is a stage of a Jenkins Pipeline build. You can run manually first (e.g. from the Dev Console) if you are not using a CI server.

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to resolve this - had same issue.

Created new user in my scratch org using sfdx :

```
sfdx force:user:create --setalias qa-user
```

Open the org went to Roles created a new Role and assigned it to new User. (apparently you cannot assign to existing role).

I'm now able to create Account with owner that has a role - which means I can create a portal account and contact for testing.